# Thawte signed jar file not working in Micromax mobile?

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, code-signing, thawte

I had purchased the certificate from Thawte and with that I signed my jar file. The thawte signed jar file is working in Nokia and sony mobiles but it's not working in LG and Micromax.
Showing 'The Java AP is not verified'. Any idea and solution on this. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the certificate with which you have signed your jad is not verified root authority for Nokia,Sony . call their technical person and ask for the detail with model no.

Answer (score 0):

May be your phone doesn't have installed this certificate. Insure it in `Security` options in your phone settings.